# Posting the checkbox value using hardcoded string value using serialize() works but not working while using value.toString() in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

Trying to post the checkbox data using `serialize()` in ajax. The data is in object format and converted to string data using `value.toString()` and passed as parameter to api but the api didn't work. When used a hardcoded data instead it worked!

I am trying to post the checkbox data to the backend using `serialize()` but the function never starts nor the data is being send to the backend. I have used `value.Join(",")`, still it does not work.

The code:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr("ID");
  
  if (confirm("Update")) {
    $('#update').modal('show');
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  $('#update_form').on("submit", function() {
    var update = [];
    
    $.each($("input[name='Ucheckbox[]']:checked"), function() {
      update.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    var un = update.join(",");
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "url/api",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#update_form').serialize() + "&id=" + id + "&un=" + un,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(res) {
        alert('Error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But when assigned a hardcoded string value in un variable the redirection to backend works and the values are received at the backend.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr("ID");
  var un = "1,2,3"

  $.ajax({
    url: "url/api",
    method: "POST",
    data: $('#update_form').serialize() + "&id=" + id + "&un=" + un,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(res) {
      alert('Error');
    }
  });
});

});
```

I want the data to be converted to string and passed as parameter to backend.

Comment: There is another difference in the second code block: there is no ``on('submit'`` listener. Did you try the hard coded string with that second listener? Maybe it is the ID that causes the issue...

Comment: Yes, when i placed the hardcoded value in on('submit') it was not working. How can i get the checkbox value in this case.